# How to reload/deploy moleculer services in production?

Tags: moleculer

How should i deploy new versions of molecular services?
The [documentation](https://moleculer.services/docs/0.13/runner.html#Options) explains well how to start them with `moleculer-runner`, but i can't find what is the proper way reload them without downtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero-downtime updating is not part of the framework, it's a system admin/devops issue. I recommend using Kubernetes for deploying upgraded containers with zero-downtime: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/